# get height of nodeList load via ajax with javascript

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I am loading in some html using YUI3, that looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <p>This is all of my content, neat neat neat!!!!</p>
  <img src="ps_logo.png" alt="Google" />
</div>
```

I've tried using `.get('offsetHeight')` and `.getComputedStyle('height')`, but both only return the height of the div and paragraph tag and don't take into account the height of the image.  So, even though the image is 150px tall, I am getting 73px returned.

Whats the best way to get the width and height of a nodeList when the elements haven't had it set via CSS?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the image loaded before you're calling this? It's entirely possible that that **is** the height at the time of invocation, and then image loads and it makes it bigger.

Comment: well, I am waiting until the ajax call in complete before I check the height.

Answer (score 0):

Either set the img height in the img tag - account for it, or ensure that the height query is called *after* the image has loaded, not just after the image tag has been put in the page.